# Jquery val don't set new value to a textbox

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I use jqueryUI autocomplete to search in geo names, but I can't set value to my textbox
here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        function log(message) {
            $("#appendedInputButton").val(message);
        }
        $("#appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                                value: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my HTML is:

```
<div class="input-append">
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://sushiant.com/">
        <button class="btn" type="submit" id="searchsubmit">جستجو</button>
        <input class="span2" name="appendedInputButton" id="appendedInputButton" size="16" type="text" style="width: 300px;">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Poorly formatted code is considerably less readable, and that's potentially going to put people off even looking at your question (speaking for myself that's definitely true). You can use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to easily format your code.

Comment: Any error message in console (F12)? Ahe you tried to debug your code using break point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Replace the success function with the following:

```
success: function (data) {
    response($.map(data.geonames, function (item) {
        var text = item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName;
        return {
            label: text,
            value: text
        }
    }));
}
```

I guessed the `"Selected: "` part was here for debug purpose only, so basically what you're looking to do is set both `label` and `value` to the same string.

### Explanation

The call to `val()` works perfectly fine. You don't see the expected result though because the value is overwritten with the `value` field set in your `response`  callback function, which is the default behavior of `autocomplete`.

Moreover, the `select` event should never be called with `ui.item` undefined, as it precisely reacts to the selection of an item... so the `"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);` alternative should never be reached anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
$("#appendedInputButton").attr('value',message);
```

Comment: No, let's not. For a start, you want to be setting the `value` **property**, not the `value` attribute, so at the very least you should use `.prop()`. However, the `.val()` method is designed explicitly and specifically to set the value of an element, why on earth would you think the choice of function is the problem?

Comment: JQuery val() function is used to do that, exactly as the OP use it.